# Django Multiple JQuery Use In templates

Tags: jquery, django

I want to write some JQuery code in multiple templates. However, I do not want to write this: 
`<script src="{% static "js/vendor/jquery-1.11.2.min.js" %}"></script>`
in every single template. Currently I have all my JQuery files defined in `base.html` like so:

```
        {% block js %}
            <script src="{% static "js/vendor/jquery-1.11.2.min.js" %}"></script>
            <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="{% static "js/vendor/jquery-1.11.2.min.js" %}"><\/script>')</script>
            <script src="{% static "js/vendor/bootstrap.min.js" %}"></script>
            <script src="{% static "js/plugins.js" %}"></script>
            <script src="{% static "js/main.js" %}"></script>
        {% endblock %}
```

and then in my other templates I wish to call them like this:

```
//Child.html

{% block js %}
    {{ block.super }} 
    <script>
        ...Some JQuery Code...
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

But it is not working. Any ideas?

Comment: What about simply including your script tags outside the js block? Then you don't need to mess with `block.super`.

Comment: But I don't want to be doing that for multiple templates. Isn't there something more elegant?

Comment: if all your child templates are based off of base.html then putting them outside any block in the base template will include them in every template